# Continuity of the function $f(x)=\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos t}{x^2+t^2}dt.$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, improper-integrals

How to prove that function $f(x)=\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos t}{x^2+t^2}dt$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}?$ By fundamental theorem of calculus I know that indefinite  integral $\int_{1}^{x}\frac{\cos t}{x^2+t^2}dt$ is continuous but not having idea for this type of improper integral. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Hint: Use the uniform convergence of the integral.

Comment: i know the result that if a sequence of continuous function converges uniformly then limit function is also continuous. But did not got the exact point.

Comment: @PeterForeman dt........................

Comment: if possible please give solution i details . Thanks...

Comment: @PeterForeman i edited the question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The continuity of $f(x)=\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(t)}{x^2+t^2}dt$ follows from the following inequality: for $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ we have that
$$|f(x)-f(y)|= \left|\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(t)(y^2-x^2)}{(y^2+t^2)(x^2+t^2)}dt\right|\leq |x^2-y^2|\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{dt}{t^4}=\frac{|x^2-y^2|}{3}.$$
Therefore,  if $x\to y$ then $\frac{|x^2-y^2|}{3}\to 0$ and, by comparison, $f(x)\to f(y)$.

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: Yes ...I think this one is nice...

Comment: now will i compare it to $x^2$ in last step?

Comment: Just note that when $x\to y$ then $\frac{|x^2-y^2|}{3}\to 0$ and therefore, by comparison, $f(x)\to f(y)$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $x_n \to x_0$.

Then $$g_n(t)=\frac{\cos{t}}{x_n^2+t^2} \to \frac{\cos{t}}{x_0^2+t^2}$$

Also $|g_n(t)| \leq \frac{1}{t^2}\in L^1([1,+\infty))$

So from Dominated Convergence Theorem we have the desired conclusion.